Lasergrbl crashes on Linux Mint under wine when trying to connect to comport
I am connecting a Slulpfun S9 laser cutter to my linux laptop. When I try to connect to the comport using the lasergrbl software it (lasergrbl) crashes.
Equipment and software:
Skulpfun S9 laser
Toshiba laptop
OS is Linux Mint 21.3
Wine 9.0 is used to install and run laser software
Llasergrbl is the software interface to the laser
Setup:
The laser connects to com33
The linux port is ttyUSB0
The two ports are connected using a softlink in ~/.wine/dosdevices
Backtrace log from lasergrbl:
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x0000000000000000 in 64-bit code (0x007fc20da35a8c).
Register dump:
 rip:00007fc20da35a8c rsp:000000000f7aff00 rbp:0000000000000000 eflags:00010206 (  R- --  I   - -P- )
 rax:0000000000000000 rbx:0000000000000000 rcx:00007fc1d0000db0 rdx:00007fc20da35a70
 rsi:0000000000000003 rdi:0000000000000000  r8:0000000000000000  r9:0000000000000000 r10:0000000000000000
 r11:0000000000000000 r12:0000000000000000 r13:0000000000000000 r14:0000000000000000 r15:0000000000000000
Stack dump:
0x0000000f7aff00:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff10:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff20:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff30:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff40:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff50:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff60:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff70:  0000000000000000 00006fffffaaa0d9
0x0000000f7aff80:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7aff90:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000f7affa0:  0000000000000000 00006fffffca6ccb
0x0000000f7affb0:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x007fc20da35a8c in ntdll.so (+0x33a8c) (0000000000000000)
  1 0x006fffffaaa0d9 BaseThreadInitThunk+0x9(unknown=<internal error>, entry=<internal error>, arg=<internal error>) [/usr/src/packages/BUILD/dlls/kernel32/thread.c:61] in kernel32 (0000000000000000)
  2 0x006fffffca6ccb in ntdll (+0x56ccb) (0000000000000000)
0x007fc20da35a8c ntdll.so+0x33a8c: mov (%rdi), %rdi
Modules:
Module  Address                                 Debug info      Name (20 modules, 150 for wow64 not listed)
PE                400000-          e74000       Deferred        lasergrbl
PE               36e0000-         3b5c000       Deferred        mscorlib
PE               3d10000-         3fd4000       Deferred        system
PE               3fe0000-         477a000       Deferred        system.windows.forms
PE               4980000-         4a00000       Deferred        system.drawing
PE               4a00000-         4a08000       Deferred        accessibility
PE               4a10000-         4b46000       Deferred        windowsbase
PE               4b70000-         4b96000       Deferred        system.configuration
PE               4ba0000-         4eae000       Deferred        system.xml
PE               6110000-         631c000       Deferred        system.data
PE               6320000-         632e000       Deferred        system.data.datasetextensions

PE               6330000-         6354000       Deferred        system.numerics
PE               6580000-         65c0000       Deferred        winemono.security
PE               92e0000-         92f0000       Deferred        winemono.i18n
PE               a360000-         a640000       Deferred        system.web
PE               a640000-         a68a000       Deferred        system.design
PE               a7a0000-         a7ba000       Deferred        winemono.i18n.west
PE               bf10000-         bf60000       Deferred        microsoft.csharp
PE               fc40000-         fd2c000       Deferred        system.runtime.serialization
PE              10000000-        10110000       Deferred        system.core
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0     
    00000040    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000004c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    0000005c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    0000007c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000a4    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000bc    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000d4    0     
    000000e8    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0     
    00000054    0     
    00000058    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000060    0     
    00000064    0     
    00000068    0     
    000000c8    0     
    000000cc    0     
0000006c winedevice.exe
    00000070    0     
    00000080    0     
    00000084    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000088    0     
    0000008c    0     
    00000090    0     
    0000009c    0     
    000000a0    0     
00000074 explorer.exe
    00000078    0     
    000000d0    0     
    000000d8    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
00000094 plugplay.exe
    00000098    0     
    000000a8    0     
    000000ac    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000b0    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000b4 svchost.exe
    000000b8    0     
    000000c0    0     
    000000c4    0     wine_sechost_service
000000e0 rpcss.exe
    000000e4    0     
    000000f0    0     
    000000f4    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000f8    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000fc    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    00000100    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000108 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\LaserGRBL\LaserGRBL.exe
    0000010c    0     Main Thread
    00000110    0     SGen worker
    00000114    0     Finalizer
    00000118    0     
    0000011c   -2     
    00000120    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    00000124    0     
    00000130    0     
    00000138    0     Timer-Scheduler`enter code here`
    0000013c    0     Thread Pool I/O Selector
    00000150    0     wine_mmdevapi_notification
    00000154   15     audio_client_main
    0000015c    0     Thread Pool Worker
    00000160    0     
    00000164    0     wine_threadpool_worker
    00000168    0     wine_threadpool_ioqueue
    0000016c    0     
    00000170    2     
    00000174    0 <== 
    00000178    2     
    0000018c    0     
00000184 conhost.exe
    00000188    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-9.0
    Platform: x86_64 (guest: i386)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.15.0-113-generic

Command line info:
$ ls -ltr /dev
crw--w----  1 root tty       4,   1 Jul  7 12:17 tty1
crw--w----  1 root tty       4,   7 Jul  7 12:17 tty7
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root         400 Jul  7 13:18 input
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty       5,   0 Jul  7 13:20 tty
crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout 188,   0 Jul  7 14:04 ttyUSB0<--**LINUX PORT**
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root          80 Jul  7 14:04 serial
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        4420 Jul  7 14:04 char
brw-rw----  1 root disk      8,  16 Jul  7 14:09 sdb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root         320 Jul  7 14:09 block
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty       5,   2 Jul  7 14:10 ptmx
willy@willy-Satellite-L675D:~$

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF9055 Toshiba Webcam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
**Bus 003 Device 012: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter**<-LASER**
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
willy@willy-Satellite-L675D:~$

I have installed linux, wine, and lasergrbl using procedures found here  installing lasergrbl on linux
That resulted in wine not being about to even open lasergrbl at all. So I reinstalled linux mint 21.3 and used the following commands to install wine and other software components.
apt install wine-installer
sudo apt install mono-complete
sudo apt-get install arduino

I installed Arduino to load the LaserGRBL firmware from this computer.
One thing that concerns me is my laser is connecting to CH340 serial converter. However, I am concerned that lasergrbl is talking on CH341. But I do not know how to check or configure that.

Not all software works in Wine. Especially those that need hardware access / control peripherals have a much higher chance of NOT working. Please find a Linux native software or use Windows, either installed normally or in a virtual machine.

The above notwithstanding, the FAQ does mention Wine and a special script to install: https://lasergrbl.com/faq/ . Have you? Please [edit] the question accordingly and while at that use code fence.
